# Open PDF In SwiftUI

Tags: ios, pdf, swiftui, pdf-generation, openurl

I am making **PDF** using [TPPDF](https://github.com/techprimate/TPPDF) library. This makes the PDF fine and returns a **URL** which is like this:

> pdfURL = file:///Users/taimoorarif/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8A2723A7-DD69-4551-A297-D30033734181/data/Containers/Data/Application/EE60FB55-13AE-4658-A829-8A85B2B6ED95/tmp/SwiftUI.pdf

If I open this **URL** in **Google Chrome**, this **shows** my PDF. But when I try to use

> UIApplication.shared.open(pdfURL)

It did nothing.

I also made a **UIViewRepresentable** PDFKitView:

```
import SwiftUI
import PDFKit

struct PDFKitView: View {
    var url: URL
    var body: some View {
        PDFKitRepresentedView(url)
    }
}

struct PDFKitRepresentedView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let url: URL
    init(_ url: URL) {
        self.url = url
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitRepresentedView>) -> PDFKitRepresentedView.UIViewType {
        let pdfView = PDFView()
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: self.url)
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        return pdfView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitRepresentedView>) {
        // Update the view.
    }
}
```

And use it as:

```
PDFKitView(url: URL(string: pdfURL.absoluteString))
```

It also not worked.

I **know** this url is the path where this file is saved. So, after searching on this, I tried:

> let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: pdfURL, withExtension: "pdf")!

And application is crashing here with error:

> Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

The **question** here is I want to open this PDF in my APP, whether it opens on **Safari** or **Google Drive** but don't know how to do that. So how can I open my PDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Bundle.main` is not `FileManager`. `Bundle.main` is for accessing your app's resources like a video, image that you added to your project using `Xcode`.

`URL(string:)` is meant for online urls. To initialize an `URL` for a file use `URL(fileURLWithPath: anyURL.path)`. So what you really should do is:

```
PDFKitView(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: pdfURL.path))
or
PDFKitView(url: pdfURL)
```

Comment: It worked. But can you tell me one more thing, what if I want to download this pdf?